# Input with Streamreader doesn't give the same output in a StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm reading a file with a StreamReader and writing the exact line to another file with a StreamWriter. The problem I have however is that in the resulting file any occurence of the character '¦' is converted to '?'.

This is the code for initializing my streams:

```
using (var readFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var writeFile = new FileStream(@"Modified\" +   Path.GetFileName(path), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(readFile, new ASCIIEncoding()))
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(writeFile, new ASCIIEncoding()))
            {
                //Read line and write it to the writer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could this be a problem with the streams or is it more likely a problem with the original file? The original file itself displays just fine in multiple text editors, so it seems correct.

Comment: when you set your breakpoints, what does it look like in the debugger?

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding to UTF8?

Comment: Clearly you don't *actually* like to use ASCIIEncoding.  If you have no clue what the text encoding might be then punt for Encoding.Default.  You ought to have a clue however.

Comment: Thing is, I was really sure it was ASCII, since Unicode didn't work. Encoding.Default did work. I don't know why exactly.

Answer (score 3):

¦ isn't a valid ASCII character so I'm assuming the original file isn't ASCII encoded.  Changing the encoding type to UTF would resolve the issue but it's difficult to know if that is valid for your requirements.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(readFile, new UTF8Encoding()))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(writeFile, new UTF8Encoding()))
```

See http://www.asciitable.com/ fpr the valid ascii character list.

Comment: I checked multiple sites that gave me 166 as the ASCII value for the ¦, so I assumed it was part of the ASCII set

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by using Encoding.Default instead of ASCIIEncoding.